# Prevent drag and drop default across ember application

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to prevent the default drag and drop feature across an ember application. I have tried using the drop events and `event.preventDefault()` in the controller, but I am pretty sure they are only available in components. I also tried adding `ondragstart="return false;" ondragenter="return false;" ondrop="return false;" dragover="return false;" dragleave="return false;"` to the body tag in index html. What is the proper way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent default events from being listened to, just define corresponding event to null. [Reference](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-views/lib/system/event_dispatcher.js#L45)

```
let App = Ember.Application.create({
      customEvents: {
        dragstart: null,
        drag: null,
        dragenter: null,
        dragleave: null,
        dragover: null,
        drop: null,
        dragend: null
      }
    });
```

if you are using ember-cli then in `App.js` file,

```
App = Ember.Application.extend({
    modulePrefix: config.modulePrefix,
    podModulePrefix: config.podModulePrefix,
    Resolver,
    customEvents: {
        dragstart: null,
        drag: null,
        dragenter: null,
        dragleave: null,
        dragover: null,
        drop: null,
        dragend: null
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.no-drag{
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  user-drag: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
```

add this class to your tag.